# Pokemon TCG: is there a way to remove energy from your own pokemon?

Tags: pokemon

I'm starting to get into Pokemon TCG with my daughter and after the first few games I already have some questions to which I cannot find an answer in the official rulebook. One of them is - is there a way to remove an energy card from one of **your own** Pokemon?

I've found there are [some](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Energy_Removal_(Base_Set_92)) [cards](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Super_Energy_Removal_(Base_Set_79)) that allow you to remove energy from your opponent's pokemon - which is also useful - but what about your own? Like, if I see that my Pokemon will soon be knocked out and I want to salvage the attached energy card(s), is there a way to do that? The rulebook doesn't mention that at all, and Google searching doesn't turn up any cards like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I can answer my own question after all. After some more searching I came across the [Energy Reset](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Energy_Reset_(Fates_Collide_98)) and [Energy Pouch](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Energy_Pouch_(Fates_Collide_97)) cards. Since there are cards like that, that means you can't do it on a whim, but it *is* possible, if you have the right card.

Comment: Correct, the more powerful cards move energy around on your pokemon, since you are limited to playing one energy per turn normally.  I have seen games lost because a player had no more energy in there deck.  Pokemon is a game about knowing how to use your resources including your energy attachments.

Answer (score 3):

> if I see that my Pokemon will soon be knocked out and I want to salvage the attached energy card(s)

There are some specific cards for that purpose.

> [Wishful Baton](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-tcg/pokemon-cards/sm-series/sm3/128/): If the Pokémon this card is attached to is your Active Pokémon and is Knocked Out by damage from an opponent's attack, move up to 3 basic Energy cards from that Pokémon to 1 of your Benched Pokémon.
>
> [Exp. Share](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-tcg/pokemon-cards/sm-series/sm1/118/): When your Active Pokémon is Knocked Out by damage from an opponent's attack, you may move 1 basic Energy card from that Pokémon to the Pokémon this card is attached to.
>
> [Energy Switch](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-tcg/pokemon-cards/sm-series/sm1/117/): Move a basic Energy from 1 of your Pokémon to another of your Pokémon.

Plus several others, Multi-Switch, for example (which allows moving any type of energy).

Answer (score 1):

The placement of energy is one of the main allocation of resources in the game.  There are cards and pokemon that allow you to pick or move your energy but under most situation you can't move your energy around.  If this was allowed then the limit on special energy would mater less since you could pick it up at any time and decks that could place multiply energy in one turn would be even more powerful.  Also it would break item like max potion which downside is discarding all energy attached to the pokemon.